# Expectations are not recorded for injectable instances

Tags: jmockit

Here is my code and I am doing code coverage testing

```
public class RegisterTest {
 @Tested Register register;


    @Test
    public void testGetStudentName(@Injectable final Student student) {

        new NonStrictExpectations(){
            {
                student.getRollNo();
                result="ab1";

            }
            };


            assertEquals(register.getStudentNo(), "ab1");       

    }
}
```

I got assertion  error for the above testcase because the injectable instance doesnt work here..I dont know y?

Here is my testclass...

Register.class

```
public class Register {

    Student student=new Student();

public  String getStudentNo(){

        return student.getRollNo();

    }


}
```

Here is my dependency class

Student.class

```
public class Student {

    String name;
        int age;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

How can I resolve that assertion error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Injectable` mock used in the test does work. However, it is never injected into the tested object, which instead creates its own `Student` instance. So, in situations like this you use `@Mocked`, not `@Injectable`.

I should point out two other things, though:

1. Please take notice of the API documentation. The JMockit jar files (even the Maven ones) contain source code precisely to facilitate access to API documentation from any Java IDE.
2. "Value classes" like `Student` (which merely contain getters/setters) are not good candidates for mocking. In general, they should not be mocked. Instead, real instances should be used.